# how to create war file from command line using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am creating a war file using ansible, below is the code i am using

```
- name: Create test.war file
  command: jar -cf test.war *
  args:
    chdir: /tmp/testFolder/
```

But I am getting below error

```
  "rc": 1,
    "start": "2019-09-13 15:20:03.759503",
    "stderr": "* : no such file or directory",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "* : no such file or directory"
```

Can anyone help me to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `*` is expanded by the shell, but when running [`command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html), you don't have a shell.

What you can use instead to make it work is the [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) module:

```
- name: Create test.war file
  shell: jar -cf test.war *
  args:
    chdir: /tmp/testFolder/
```

Otherwise, you have to specify a shell in order to expand it:

```
- name: Create test.war file
  command: /bin/sh -c 'jar -cf test.war *'
  args:
    chdir: /tmp/testFolder/
```

(All credits for that second solution goes to [*redbaron*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/5675#issuecomment-32679485))